# RabbitMQ cluster on a single machine

Tags: rabbitmq, rhel, rabbitmqctl, rhel8

I want to create a three node RabbitMQ cluster on a single RHEL8 machine for testing purposes. I tried instructions given in [RabbitMQ official guide](https://www.rabbitmq.com/clustering.html#single-machine) and also tried to follow [this guide](https://javamana.com/2021/01/20210103074034286Z.html).
The first node works fine and it's running. However, the second node cannot be started and throws up an error.

I used below commands as mentioned in the guide.

```
RABBITMQ_NODE_PORT=5672 RABBITMQ_NODENAME=rabbit rabbitmq-server -detached 

RABBITMQ_NODE_PORT=5673 RABBITMQ_NODENAME=hare rabbitmq-server -detached 

rabbitmqctl -n hare stop_app
```

This command throws up below error.

## DIAGNOSTICS

attempted to contact: [hare@localhost]

hare@localhost:

- connected to epmd (port 4369) on localhost
- epmd reports: node 'hare' not running at all
  other nodes on localhost: [rabbit]

On further inspection of logs, it seems like that this node tries to use the same ports used by the first node (e.g. MQTT port 1883).

I think I might have to use the other option of declaring /etc/rabbitmq/rabbitmq.conf. Mainly because it seems to give more options to change ports etc.

A sample config file resembling the one needed in my case or a link to a proper guide is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't specify, but you must have the MQTT plugin enabled for there to be a conflict on that port, correct?

The easiest work-around would be to have *two* configuration files specifying different ports for MQTT, AMQP and anything else. Then, use the `RABBITMQ_CONFIG_FILE` environment variable to point to the appropriate file:

```
RABBITMQ_NODE_PORT=5672 RABBITMQ_NODENAME=rabbit0 \
    RABBITMQ_CONFIG_FILE=/path/to/rabbitmq-0.conf rabbitmq-server -detached

RABBITMQ_NODE_PORT=5673 RABBITMQ_NODENAME=rabbit1 \
    RABBITMQ_CONFIG_FILE=/path/to/rabbitmq-1.conf rabbitmq-server -detached
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Yes. you were right. I had enabled MQTT plugin, rabbitmq_management plugin as instructed in the guide I have mentioned. I disabled all those and started everything again and it worked. Actually I didn't create separate configuration files, but used commands I have mentioned earlier. However only 'rabbit' node is up after a restart and other two nodes in the cluster aren't running. What would be the best option to keep all nodes running after a restart?

Comment: Running a cluster on a single machine is only useful for development. In production, you should be using separate servers that run the official packages and are managed my systemd or your system's init.

Comment: Yes. I was using this for testing only. But as I had to turnoff my machine sometimes, I wanted to see if each node could be managed by a separate systemd instance. But I got the point you've made. Thanks!